# retrieve state from leveldb

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to retrieve the latest state from the local disk leveldb. I first get the latest block "currentBlock" from the leveldb, which works fine. Then I use the function loadLastState in go-ethereum source code, the corresponding state "currentBlock.Root()" is not found. Then I did into the low level function trie.OpenTrie, it cannot find the corresponding state by the stateRoot.

My question is whether the state is stored on the local disk? Or just the blocks are stored on disk? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flag configCache to enable archival mode (Disabled=True), where the program will flush every block received into the disk. Then when we restart the program, the latest block and state can be retrieved.